# How to display json content for every \n on a new line in python

Tags: python, json

I have this output from a file

```
file = open('path', 'r')
file_content = file.read()

file_content = 
123
123
123
```

I'm creating the following json to serve as reply for a api using flask:

```
var = file_content 
return jsonify({'result':var})
```

The curl output is

```
123\n123\n123\n
```

Is there a way to make the json display as such, every single "123" on a new line and the '\n' removed? :

```
{result: '123
123
123'
```

Even an article would be good to guide me on how to accomplish this, basically I want to prittyprint the response..

flask code as reference:

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import start, tempData
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])


@app.route('/test<int:num>', methods=['GET'])
def callMainF(num):

    start.cicleInfotypes(num)

    return jsonify({'result':tempData.getOuput()})
```

Comment: if the `f` variable in `f.read()` an opened file?

Comment: Yup, didn't thought to include it, will edit asap.

Comment: I don't think json lets you have a newline inside a string. Do you just want the output format to be prettier?

Comment: Yeah basically, I wanna have 1 tag and the tag.text to be a string, which i want to be formatted basically, because at the moment it generates a 1000 character line which is very hard to read.

Comment: Like copying a text from a book page and do something like, `{'bookpage1': 'AllTheTextFromAPage'}`

Comment: As in somehow beautify the value for a tag

Comment: I don't think it would be valid json with multiple lines of text, is it acceptable to put each line in a list?

Comment: Yes, each line as a list should do perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "display" each line separately by splitting the lines into a list. Here is an example:

```py
import json

def open_txt(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return file.readlines() # return a list of lines

# lines = open_txt('./data.txt') # uncomment if you want \n character at the end of lines
lines = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in open_txt('./data.txt')] # remove the \n character

# put it into a dict and prettify the output
print(json.dumps({'lines': lines}, indent=4))
```

Input (data.txt):

```
these
are
multiple
lines
```

Output:

```
{
    "lines": [
        "these",
        "are",
        "multiple",
        "lines"
    ]
}
```

Here is some background on multiple ways python prints strings:

```py
import json

lines = 'these\nare\nmultiple\nlines'
print(lines)
print({'lines': lines})
print(json.dumps({'lines': [line for line in lines.split('\n')]}, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
these
are
multiple
lines
{'lines': 'these\nare\nmultiple\nlines'}
{
    "lines": [
        "these",
        "are",
        "multiple",
        "lines"
    ]
}
```